# GetTickCount equivalent in kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Actually to be more specific I want to get the time an IRQ is triggered. Im used to using GetTickCount and I'm wondering what time mechanism can be used inside a linux kernel module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `jiffies` variable in the Linux kernel that holds the number of ticks since system start. Look for example [here](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec3).